# Is there a generic term for local storage media?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, storage

Although hard drives are still ubiquitous, SSDs (solid state drives) are becoming more and more popular,

However, it's more typical to hear "I saved it to my hard drive". When's the last time you ever heard someone say "I saved it to my SSD?"

I believe this is because of the conventional relationship where hard drive = local computer storage, to differentiate it from network storage, cloud storage, etc...

But in a world where local computer storage can be stored on a variety of types of disks nowadays, what is a more generic "all-encompassing" way to refer collectively to local computer storage, including both hard drives and SSDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you named it best when you called it "local storage". If you want to be particular about it being non-removable, "local fixed storage".

Specific to Windows, I note that "Disk drive(s)" is used to describe both hard drives and SSDs in Device Manager on Windows 10. This carries the same connotation as LFS but is short, sweet and already universally known and understood.